# Android - Draw a rectangle

Tags: android, android-emulator

How can I draw rectangle at start and end points but still maintain the same width? ie 10 pixels width.

Rect simplr = new Rect();

simplr.set(start.x, start.y, end.x, end.y);

thank you

Comment: simplr.set(x1, y1, x1+10, y2) ?

Answer (score 0):

Thickness is normally something you set in the `Paint`, not in the `Rect`.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setStrokeWidth(float)

Comment: Sorry I meant width, not stroke.

Comment: Can you pls. give a sample of what u want to do then? Sounds like some basic math?